# CakePHP: Error: The view for TasksController::index() was not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I  use CakePHP 2.5.5 . My project in this directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\vy\cakephp-2.5.5 . My project directory layout:
[image]

I have been created file *C:\xampp\htdocs\vy\cakephp-2.5.5\app\Model\task.php* (**Model**)with content:

```
<?php

class Task extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Task';
}

?>
```

I have been created file *C:\xampp\htdocs\vy\cakephp-2.5.5\app\Controller\TasksController.php* (**Controller**) with content:

```
<?php

class TasksController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Tasks';

    function index()
    {
        $this->set('tasks', $this->Task->find('all'));
    }
}

?>
```

I have been created file *C:\xampp\htdocs\vy\cakephp-2.5.5\app\View\Task\index.ctp* (**View**) with content:

```
<h2>Tasks</h2>
<?php if (empty($tasks)): ?>
    There are no tasks in this list
<?php else : ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Modified</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($tasks as $task): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $task['Task']['title'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if ($task['Task']['done']) echo "Done";
                    else echo "Pending";
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $task['Task']['created'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php if ($task['Task']['modified']) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- actions on tasks will be added later -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When run program, error:

> ```
> Missing View
> Error: The view for TasksController::index() was not found.
>
> Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\xampp\htdocs\vy\cakephp-2.5.5\app\View\Tasks\index.ctp
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_view.ctp
> ```

[image]

How to repair above application? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is read the error message carefully :)

The view folder should be `View\Tasks` (plural) instead of `View\Task` as you currently have.

Also your model file name should be `Task.php` not `task.php`. Be carefully of case sensitivity in file names. While things will work on windows if you move files to a linux server you will get errors as it has case sensitive filesystem.

Comment: when I follow your instruction, rename, task.php --> Task.php `Error: Notice (8): Undefined index: Tasks [APP\View\Tasks\index.ctp, line 16]` I must change in code, too. Thank you